# Center div in between toolbars on iPhone Safari?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I'd like to vertically center a div on iPhone when the address bar and toolbar show. I can make this work in landscape when the browser goes fullscreen...

[image: Div is vertically centered when toolbars aren't showing]

but as soon as the toolbars show up, the div becomes not centered.

[image]

Is there a way to make the div centered with respect to the visible part of the window without using Javascript?

Here's my current code:

```
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50vh - 25px);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width initial-scale=1.0' />
</head>

<body>
  <div>Centered?</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a `div` inside your `div`. You then give that embedded div a `width: 100%` and `max-width: 1000px`, and with that `max-width` you set, you also add `margin: 0 auto;` to center it. As for your text, that is nothing more than text-align: center;

My suggestion for your solution is:

HTML:

```
<div class="parentclass">
    <div class="childclass">Centered?</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

div.parentclass {
    width: 100%;
    }
    div.childclass{
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        width:100%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        text-align:center;
        }
```